# convert single array by two dimensional array by 6

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert and merge my single array to two dimensional array. I use map for that but I can't achieve the output I want. May I ask any suggestion on how to achieve this?

The data is below:

```
          var singelArr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','a','b','c','d','e','f','a','b','c','d','e','f'];

          var doubleArr = [
                                ['','','','','',''],
                                ['','','','','',''],
                                ['','','','','',''],
                                ['','','','','',''],
                                ['','','','','',''],

                          ]
```

And now my expected output is:

```
 output = [
           ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
           ['b','c','d','e','a','f'],
           ['b','c','d','e','a','f'],
           ['','','','','',''],
           ['','','','','','']

 ];
```

What I've done so far is https://jsfiddle.net/jc3v25bs/. I can display the data element by 6 but the problem is I am not sure how can I merge it to my `doubleArr` variable. I also prefer something that it will loop faster.

Any idea is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `slice()` function to split the first array. Then you could create your output by concatenating the result with the last part of the second array.

```js
let singleArr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','a','b','c','d','e','f','a','b','c','d','e','f'];

let doubleArr = [
  ['','','','','',''],
  ['','','','','',''],
  ['','','','','',''],
  ['','','','','',''],
  ['','','','','',''],

];

let chunkedArr = [];
for(i=0,j=0; i<singleArr.length; i+=6, j++){
    chunkedArr[j] = singleArr.slice(i, i+6);
}
let output = chunkedArr.concat(doubleArr.slice(chunkedArr.length));

console.log(output);
```